# Dual Booting a Macbook Pro (OSX) with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, unix

I have been trying to dual boot my mid-2012 Macbook Pro running OSX Mountain Lion with Ubuntu 12.10 with a disk and a USB, and none of them are working. I have used disk utility to partition my hard drive for linux and burn the .iso image to the external drives (usb and dvd).

The only thing that happens at the end, is that the disk becomes useless by giving this message: "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

I have gone into terminal and burned my iso through terminal, too. I also tried to do it with Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 12.10 with the same outcome.

BTW, for reference, I did the exact same thing as explained in [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware), except they can burn the dvd and I can't. Maybe this Ubuntu download is meant for Windows?

Also, I have rebooted my mac holding c and also tried selecting the cd by holding the option (alt) key. Nothing shows up.

I really don't know what the problem is. I wasted 5 dvd's, 2 cd's, and a USB. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried---or can you try---following this tutorial for the USB? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 1):

I had a sucessful live USB boot on a MacBook Pro mid 2012 with Ubuntu 13.04. I just followed the [official tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Try uninstalling rEFIt. The live boot doesn't require it: just press <kbd>alt</kbd> at boot and select the live USB.

If you still have problems, I recommend you the [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which is currently developed (rEFIt is abandoned).

Before you install Ubuntu from the live CD/USB, I recommend to do the partitioning from Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

[Linux USB Creator for Mac](http://penguintosh.com/tag/linux-usb-creator/).

Instructions:

- First just select the linux distribution you want to use. You can either select from the list or browse for a Local ISO file to use.
- After selecting your chosen distribution you can browse for your USB device.
- The program will then download the ISO, Format the disk, Copy the ISO and Install the Bootloader.
- Your USB Drive is now ready to use. Simply boot up your mac while holding the “alt” key and select the drive.

Please Note: This program has not been updated since the introduction of OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.